# Newton's method for unconstrained optimization applied to a quartic function in R2

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am faced with the task of applying Newton's method to the following problem:

$$ \text{min} ~~~~~ 8x_1x_2+\frac{1}{4}(x_1-x_2)^4 $$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$. For clarification, the Newton method to which I am referring is:

$$ x^{k+1} = x^{k} - \left(\nabla^2f(x^k)\right)^{-1}\nabla f(x^k) $$

where $f$ represents the objective function to be minimized, $\nabla f$ represents the gradient of $f$ as usual, and $\nabla^2f$ represents the Hessian of $f$.

I have already shown that for a choice of an initial $x^0 := (x_1^0,x_2^0)$ such that $3(x_1^0-x_2^0)^2 \neq4$ all the resulting iterates $x^k := (x_1^k,x_2^k)$ lie on the line $x_1^k+x_2^k=0$.

Where I am running into a roadblock is attempting to show two things:

Firstly: if one chooses a step length of one, then it converges to $(0,0)$ (a saddle point) cubically if $|x_1^0-x_2^0| < \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$.

Secondly: again using a unit step length it converges to a global minimum (which is not unique for this problem - it is attained at both $(1,-1) ~ \text{and} ~ (-1,1)$) if we take $3(x_1^0-x_2^0)^2>4$.

I fought with some unruly algebra to achieve the one result I've mentioned and I can't seem to make anything meaningful come out in the wash to show the remaining results.

Comment: What do you mean by a step length of $1$?  Is that the same as unit step length?  Usually the step length is the second term in your second equation, which can vary widely.

Comment: I believe you're right, thank you, my apologies. I edited out my original parenthetical. So we would have to normalize the second term to guarantee a step size of one.

Comment: You still have the phrase "step length of one".  The step length in Newton's method varies by every step.  $|x^{k+1}-x^k|$ is whatever it is based on your second equation.  Maybe you think of stepping some factor times the second term in the equation.  If so, you will destroy the quadratic convergence of Newton's method, but it will probably still converge.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate $x^{k+1}$ as a function of $x^k$?  It seems straightforward, but some work.  If so, please show the result.  If not, please explain where you have difficulty.